# How do I analyse a URL in Perl?

Tags: perl

I want `http://www.foo.com/bar.html` from `http://www.foo.com/bar.html?key=value...`.

A regexp should do the work. Is there some module to do this? I checked [URI](http://p3rl.org/URI), it seems does not have such sub.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also try [URI::URL](http://p3rl.org/URI%3a%3aURL).

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use URI::URL;

my $path = 'http://www.foo.com/bar.html?key=value';

my $url = URI::URL->new($path);

my $new_url = URI::URL->new();

$new_url->scheme( $url->scheme );
$new_url->host( $url->host );
$new_url->path( $url->path );

print $new_url->as_string();
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `URI` this way:

```
sub remove_query_string($)
{
    my $uri = URI->new(shift);
    $uri->query(undef);
    return $uri->as_string;
}
```

But yeah, you definitely could use a regex for this:

```
sub remove_query_string($)
{
    my $ret = shift;
    $ret =~ s/\?.*//;
    return $ret;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The [URI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?URI) module includes the methods/mechanisms:

```
 $u1 = URI->new("http://www.perl.com");
 $u2 = URI->new("foo", "http");
 $u3 = $u2->abs($u1);
 $u4 = $u3->clone;
 $u5 = URI->new("HTTP://WWW.perl.com:80")->canonical;

 $str = $u->as_string;
 $str = "$u";

 $scheme = $u->scheme;
 $opaque = $u->opaque;
 $path   = $u->path;
 $frag   = $u->fragment;

 $u->scheme("ftp");
 $u->host("ftp.perl.com");
 $u->path("cpan/");
```

For your problem, you would concatenate the scheme (`http`) and the opaque section (everything between the scheme and fragment) would give you the information you're after.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a module that does it, but this should do it for you:

```
sub getRootOfURL()
{
    my ($baseurl, undef) = split(/\?/, shift);
    return $baseurl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

why to use some fat module instead of a simple regexp

```
($base)=$url=~/^(.+)\?/;
```

Comment: Because modules express the intent better than a generic operation. ["… programs must be written for people to read, and only incidentally for machines to execute."](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/front/node3.html)

Comment: Oh! Sorry, I always thought that programs must be written to work fast, be comfortable and do it job right, and only incidentally for someone to read...

Comment: This is also true. However, when weighing readability versus saving memory like in the original premise of your answer, readability always wins. Do not optimise prematurely. An optimisation rewrite rarely becomes necessary, but it is a certainty that the piece of code is going to be read a dozen times by the maintenance programmers. I wouldn't make life difficult for them on purpose.